# how to concatenate a dynamic image path in background image url ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to concatenate a static path which will be static  and a dynamic path which is the path of the image, into image URL I am getting syntax error whenever I add + between the paths  i have tried this

```
<div *ngFor="let cat of Cat" class="cus-col" style="background-image: url( 'Static Image Url'  '+ Dynamic Image Url'  ) ">}
        <div class="cus-text">
          <h4>{{cat.name}}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Ionic, you should use Angular **NgStyle** directive to set an elements style.

This example sets the background-image of a div with a dynamic url:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + dynamicVariable + ')'}"></<div>
```

This example sets the background-image of a div with a static and dynamic url:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(https://www.example.com/images/' + dynamicVariable + ')'}"></<div>
```

You can learn more about it here:

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/